# ICC calculation for examiner and timepoint

Tags: r, intraclass-correlation

How do I calculate an ICC for a dataset in which there are k examiners, and each examiner takes n measurements? I know that I can use the psych package in R to calculate the ICC across the k*n measures for each sample, and I can calculate the ICC manually using function

```
lmer(x~1+(1|examiner)+(1|sample), data=df)
```

but I don't know how to calculate a confidence interval using lmer() or how to code the ICC() function so that it accounts for within-examiner correlation.

Comment: Is the measurement a continuous variable? What do you mean when you say "account for the two separate variables"? The only two variables here are the measurement and the identifier of the examiner.

Comment: The measurement is continuous. I mean that I can use ICC(df, missing=TRUE) to get a valid output (where df has one row for each sample and one column per measurement). However, I am pretty sure that this gets calculated as if there were n*k different examiners, instead of n measurements for k examiners.

Comment: Please add new information as an edit to the post, not only as a comment. Not everybody reads comments!